# React Hooks Form: undefined value on submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm trying to create separate input component and use React Hook Forms, Here is component:

```
export default function TextInput({label, id, placeholder, name, ...params}) {

  return (
    <FormGroup>
      <Label htmlFor={id}> {label} </Label>
      <Input
        className="form-control"
        placeholder={placeholder}
        name={name}
        id={id}
        {...params}
      />
    </FormGroup>
  );
}
```

and I'm calling it like this:

```
const {register, handleSubmit} = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  }
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                <TextInput
                  label="input password"
                  placeholder="password"
                  name="password"
                  {...register("password")}
                  id="password"
                  type="password"
                />
                <button type="submit">submit</button>
              </form>
```

But when I click submit, password seems to be undefined

[image]

React-hook-version is 7.33, any ideas about what is the problem?

Comment: please show the schema you have defined.

Comment: the `params` prop contains a ref. You cannot directly pass refs down to children. did you use forwardRef for the component?

Answer (score 1):

lets say you passed the a varible to get value from Input Field.

and next step will be to give this input field a function so that it can update the value of that variable in your case passowrd.
to do that I will use onChange.

```
<input onChange={(event)=>{resister.password = event.target.value}}/>
```

or

```
<input onChange={(event)=>{resister['password'] = event.target.value}}/>
```

and according to useForm documentation
you should be using resister in `<input/>` not in  `<TextInput/>`

```
const { onChange, onBlur, name, ref } = register('firstName'); 
// include type check against field path with the name you have supplied.
        
<input 
  onChange={onChange} // assign onChange event 
  onBlur={onBlur} // assign onBlur event
  name={name} // assign name prop
  ref={ref} // assign ref prop
/>
// same as above
<input {...register('firstName')} />
```

https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register